makefile doesnt find files on codespace
I'm trying to compile a program that is being created within a Github Codespace and the Makefile cannot compile because continues to report missing files:
make: *** No rule to create target 'solution/src/main.cpp', required for 'solution/bin/main.o'. To stop
Here's the makefile:
SRC_DIR = solution/src
INC_DIR = solution/include
BIN_DIR = solution/bin

SRCS = $(SRC_DIR)/main.cpp $(SRC_DIR)/autocomplete.cpp $(SRC_DIR)/term.cpp
OBJS = $(BIN_DIR)/main.o $(BIN_DIR)/autocomplete.o $(BIN_DIR)/term.o


CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -I$(INC_DIR) -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra


all: $(BIN_DIR)/main

$(BIN_DIR)/main: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^

$(BIN_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(BIN_DIR)/*.o $(BIN_DIR)/main


file structure its looking like this:
codespace/
├── solution/
│   ├── bin/
│   ├── include/
│   │   ├── autocomplete.h
│   │   ├── term.h
│   │   └── ordlist.h
│   ├── src/
│   │   ├── main.cpp
│   │   ├── autocomplete.cpp
│   │   └── term.cpp
│   └── Makefile
└── (other files)


From which directory you invoke make?

make its inside solution, thats the file structure after a ls:
Makefile  bin  include src

So your current pwd is codespace/solution? That does not seem right, could you try to change SRC_DIR from solution/src to src? also do the same for OBJ_SRC, etc

@JoãoPauloFonsecaGomes you should set your paths relative to the Makefile location.

Your target obj and src file is not set correctly, directory named solution should not be included as you are already at codespace/solution.
Your instruction to GCC is effectively to find a dir named solution under codespace/solution and continue the search down to main.cpp, which naturally fails.
